# Verifying JDK in build.xml

Tags: java, ant

Is there any way to verify which JDK are you using inside build.xml? For example, I want to verify that I'm using Oracle's JDK, not Microsoft's.

Comment: `ant -diagnostics | find /I  "jdk"` should tell you

Comment: I got output when I tried this from terminal:

find: /I: No such file or directory
find: jdk: No such file or directory

Comment: Which terminal - cmd.exe?

Comment: Yup. And from IDEA

Comment: Very strange. What does `find /?` give you?

Comment: You need `| findstr` not `| find`